# Python 2.7 cannot import gi

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu

I try to do `import gi` in Python2.7, but it shows error `ImportError: No module named gi`.

I did `sudo apt-get install`, but I have it already:
`python-gi is already the newest version (3.24.1-2build1).`

I also have file `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.pyc`

When I try to import gi using Python3 - it works perfectly.

I have Python2.7, Python3.6 and Ubuntu 17.10.